# Why does $(5+\sqrt{3})(5-\sqrt{3})$ not conflict with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ having unique factorization?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-factorization

My intuition is to try to show that there is some irreducible element $p \in \mathbb{Q}(5)$ that divides $(5+\sqrt{3})(5-\sqrt{3})$, but I'm having trouble finding it. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$ is a field, so everything nonzero is a unit. As unique factorisations are considered up to multiplication by a unit, factorisations are trivial. Even in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt3]$, the element $5+\sqrt3$ is a unit since $(5+\sqrt3)\cdot\frac{5-\sqrt3}{22}=1$.

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thanks.

Comment: Of course the question is referring to factorizations in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $5-\sqrt3=-(1-\sqrt3)(1+2\sqrt3)$

Answer (score 4):

If one is working in $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt3]$ then one has
$$(5+\sqrt3)(5-\sqrt3)=22=2\times11.\tag{*}$$
Is this a failure of unique factorisation in $R$? No, since
$$5+\sqrt3=(1+\sqrt3)(-1+2\sqrt3),$$
$$5-\sqrt3=(-1+\sqrt3)(1+2\sqrt3),$$
$$2=(1+\sqrt3)(-1+\sqrt3),$$
and
$$11=(1+2\sqrt3)(-1+2\sqrt3).$$
Therefore (*) just shows two ways of combining factors in
$$22=(1+\sqrt3)(-1+\sqrt3)(1+2\sqrt3)(-1+2\sqrt3).$$